# Android emulator supporting ARMv8

Tags: emulation, arm64

I need to create an Android virtual device supporting ARMv8 system image on aarch32 and aarch64 both. Does Android Studio emulator support ARMv8 system image in its AVD manager? Or is there any other emulator available? Can you provide the steps for me? Thanks!

Comment: could you find anything ?

Comment: would be convenient. i actually expected this to be available already.

Comment: Latest Android SDK Manager (rev.25.2.5) still doesn't provide ARMv8 in its list of CPU/ABIs.

Comment: Today , 1 May 2019 I am trying to boot and armv8 image in the emulator but it dies at loading Zygote. No clues on what is wrong so far.

Comment: And here we are in 2022. Still nothing?

Answer (score 0):

There is a generic Android device you can use on Arm Virtual Hardware (AVH) that has an armv8 CPU: https://avh.arm.com/

It's still in beta, so you'll need to signup and get accepted, but then it should work for you with ADB